# From Java call Scala's Singleton object apply with trait

Tags: java, scala

I have a pattern in scala like:

```
object ApiConnector {
 def apply(x: String): ApiConnector = new ApiConnectorImpl(x)
}

trait ApiConnector {
...
}

class ApiConnectorImpl extends ApiConnector {...}
```

when in Java code I want to use apply method like `ApiConnector.apply("x")`
then I got an error:

> Cannot access eu.xyz.api.ApiConnector

any ideas how to access this apply method from java code ?

Comment: The best way to allow **Java** code to call **Scala** code is to define all the interfaces using **Java** `interface` then implement those in **Scala** and finally provide a **Java** `class` that does the final interop with singletons, for those you need to use the synthetic names something like `ApiContector$` search for **Java** + **Scala** interop, there are plenty of questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help ? This worked fine for me. ( Main.java and ApiConnector.scala are in the same folder )

Scala :

```
object ApiConnector {
  def apply(x: Any): ApiConnector = {
 new ApiConnectorImpl(x)
   }
}

trait ApiConnector {
 }

class ApiConnectorImpl(x : Any) extends ApiConnector {
    println("scala")
}
```

Java :

```
public class Main {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("from java ");
    ApiConnector$.MODULE$.apply("x");
}
}
```

In Java you only have to write :      `ApiConnector$.MODULE$.apply("x");`

Comment: hmm this helps ( without MODULE$ ) but I have an error than: Non-static method 'apply(eu.xxx.api.LXYZ, sttp.client3.SttpBackend<?,java.lang.Object>)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @FrancMo this is because you didn't add the .MODULE$ thing. For singleton objects the compiler will create a Java class for the object with a dollar sign added to the end, that means your ApiConnector object translates to ApiConnector$ . That Java class also has a single static field named MODULE$ to hold the single valid instance of that class. You should write ApiConnector$.MODULE$.apply("x");  and not ApiConnector$.apply("x")

Comment: But I have an issue only now in intelliJ which shows me there "Cannot access eu.teldoc.xyz.ApiConnector$", but mvn clean compile works fine.. maybe you know also how to fix this ?